# Can I install a systemd file during distcheck using $dc_install_base?

Tags: autotools, automake

I have the following Autotools code for installing a systemd service file, which must be installed outside of `$prefix` to a directory given by a pkg-config variable:

(I know this is not proper, but I can't change the way systemd works.)

**configure.ac**

```
AC_ARG_WITH([systemdsystemunitdir],
    AS_HELP_STRING([--with-systemdsystemunitdir=DIR],
        [Directory for systemd service files]),
    [],
    [with_systemdsystemunitdir=$($PKG_CONFIG --variable=systemdsystemunitdir systemd)])
AC_SUBST([systemdsystemunitdir], [$with_systemdsystemunitdir])
```

When you run `make distcheck`, your package gets installed into a temporary staging directory and then uninstalled. Since installing something outside of `$prefix` will break that, I must override the `--with-systemdsystemunitdir` configuration option for distcheck. I do it like so, since the location of the staging directory is available in the variable `$dc_install_base`. I can't pass an absolute path here, and `$prefix` or any other `$prefix`-derived variable such as `$libdir` will not be correct during the distcheck run itself.

**Makefile.am**

```
AM_DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS = \
    --with-systemdsystemunitdir=$$dc_install_base/$(systemdsystemunitdir)
```

My question is twofold:

- This feature (`$dc_install_base`) doesn't seem to be documented anywhere. Is it officially supported or an implementation detail? Usually Automake-private variables have two consecutive underscores in them, I believe.
- Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? I know the Autotools way would be to set `systemdsystemunitdir` to a subdirectory of `$prefix` by default, and let the user or the distro override it. However, it's an important requirement to me that one should be able to extract the package from the tarball, run `./configure && make` and `sudo make install` and have everything just work. If the systemd file were installed anywhere else besides the location given by pkg-config, it would not work, and what's more, fail silently.

Comment: It's safe to say that if it isn't documented, then it isn't supported.  The older a variable is, the less likely it is to use the "__" convention -- I certainly wasn't doing that in the old days.  One question is why you would need this; the basic idea behind distcheck is that the testing simulates what a user would do; and in ordinary builds this isn't available.

Comment: I should have asked the question in the form of what I was trying to do. I will edit it to reflect that, thank you for the comment!

Comment: @TomTromey Hopefully this has become a better and more answerable question now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A bit late but...

I had a similar problem with `gobject-introspection` and I (hopefully) resolved by adding a couple of configure options and something like:

```
AM_DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS= \
    --with-girdir='$$(datadir)/gir-1.0' \
    --with-typelibdir='$$(libdir)/girepository-1.0'
```

In your case I think the following should work:

```
AM_DISTCHECK_CONFIGURE_FLAGS = \
    --with-systemdsystemunitdir='$$(prefix)/$(systemdsystemunitdir)'
```

The trick is that you must protect `$(prefix)` against two expansions: the make expansion (hence the double `$$`) and the shell expansion performed during the `configure` call (hance the single quotes).